# Can I establish an SSH tunnel to elasticbeanstalk instance?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, elastic-beanstalk

It is possible to SSH to elasticbeanstalk with `eb ssh <instance>`, but it doesn't seem to be possible to create a tunnel with this executable. How can I do it, if at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use `ssh` once the underlying ec2 instance has been added to the correct security group.

In the AWS console, EC2, locate the instance and choose `actions | networking | change security groups`. Select `EC2_Prod_Default` (it has the description "SSH in and HTTP out") & press `Assign Security Groups`

Then: `ssh -i <aws credential file> -ND <port> ec2-user@<ip number or domain name>`